# Hello Everyone. I've been working on such program which it will input a word and replace it with another input. Example output below

Tags: arrays, replace

Input a word: Lorenzo

Input a character : e

Replace the character : a

The result is : Loranzo

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Okay, so I see you've been working on that program.  I have two questions:  what language have you written it in, and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Start by visiting the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Umm the question sir, is how or what ways i can possibly do that programm. I'm a beginner at programming.
My coding language sir, is Java

Comment: Just so you know; this sort of question is too broad for the site.  It'd be better for your efforts to share what you've attempted to do and where you're having trouble, but if you're having trouble getting started, this isn't the ideal place to pose this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out this code:
First you accept a string, a character variable you want to replace and a character variable you want it to be replace by through the console(or by any means). Then using a `for loop` identify where that character you just accepted lies in the string and then you use the `replace` keyword to perform your desired operation. Keep in mind that we use a count check to avoid multiple outputs being written.

```
class Sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String name = System.console().readLine();
        int count=0;
        char firstchar = System.in.read();
        char secondchar = System.in.read();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
        char check = name.charAt(i);  
        if(check==firstchar){
            count++;
            if(count<=1)
        System.out.println(name.replace(firstchar,secondchar));
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just posting code like this isn't helpful.  It's better for there to be an actual question to answer, and for you to *explain* why your solution answers it.

Comment: There was no question and even the OP posted that he is new to Java. Hence this answer @Makoto

Comment: Explanation added @Makoto

Comment: Doesn't really change the fact that there's not *really* a question here.  If you look closely, you'll notice that the OP hasn't really made an effort here.

Comment: So by downvoting my comment are you saying my answer is wrong? If so please correct me. I dont think its fair to downvote MY answer because the OP didn't make any effort. I clearly see that the OP is struggling and hence needs help from scratch and hence my answer...@Makoto

Comment: It's what it reinforces. Dump a non-attempt brief spec and sure we will all just code away no problem. People here have the right to vote however they wish (in theory). btw who said life was fair?